# Update property from MainWindow to userControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have property defined in MainWindow "ZoomSlider" , that is databound to `Slider`.

On a `UserControl` I have a `Ellipse` such that its height is bounded to `Slider` value.

**MainWindow Code**

```
<Slider 
   Grid.Column="4"  
   Value="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow,Path=ZoomSlider,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
   Maximum="46" 
   Minimum=".1" 
   LargeChange=".1" 
   Ticks="0,1,5" 
   TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
   SmallChange=".1" 
   Height="22"  
   Width="75" 
   Margin="0" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
   VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
</Slider>

<!--Content Control is the Host of a userControl which iam Setting dynamically at runtime-->

<ContentControl Name="content" BorderThickness="1"  

Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel,Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">     

</ContentControl>
```

**UserControl Code**

```
<Ellipse  Stroke="Black">
   <Ellipse.Height>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource zoomConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">

           <Binding Path="Dia" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"/>

           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="ZoomSlider" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
         NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>

      </MultiBinding>
```

**MainWindow c# code**

```
private double zoomSlider = 2;

public double ZoomSlider
{
    get { return zoomSlider; }
    set
    {
        zoomSlider = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ZoomSlider");
    }
}
```

I successfully getting the default slider value in the `UserControl`, but when `Slider`'s value property is changed its is not getting reflected in the `UserControl`.

So,bottom line how to get the updated slider value to `UserControl` `Ellipse`

**Note:**

`UserControl` is bound to a UserControl Viewmodel and so is MainWindow to Window ViewModel

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: Place a converter here `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="ZoomSlider" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
         NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>` and check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZoomSlider should have a DependencyProperty as a backing field to enable binding

```
public double ZoomSlider
{
   get { return (double)GetValue(ZoomSliderProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ZoomSliderProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ZoomSlider.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomSliderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomSlider", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(2d));
```